# SharePoint 2010 compatibility level with SQL 2014

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2014

Can we use SharePoint 2010 with SQL server 2014? At our organization we have our SharePoint farm which is currently on SharePoint 2010 with SQL server 2008 R2. We are undergoing an SQL server upgrades for all our database servers (We have technologies being used other than SharePoint) and we don't want to tie SQL upgrade process to SharePoint upgrade.

So my Question is if we can use SQL 2014 with SharePoint 2010 in any form by either running SQL server in compatibility mode or by installing any patches for SharePoint. If we can use it what are the chances that it might break something in SharePoint and how can I verify this before doing it in production environment (We have live content management website in SharePoint)? It would be great if someone who has used this combination could comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is not supported on Microsoft SQL Server 2014. Version support is determined by the equation in the following:

> In order to maintain SharePoint and SQL Server compatibility we use
>   the “SharePoint N-1 on SQL Server N+1”  equation to determine version
>   support. Using SharePoint Foundation 2010 as an example, the N release
>   of SQL Server is 2008/2008 R2 and N+1 is SQL Server 2012. For
>   Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 the N release of SQL Server is 2012
>   and the N+1 is SQL Server 2014.

What that means SharePoint 2010 is not supported on SQL 2014. There are no plans to support it in the future.

[SQL Server 2014 and SharePoint supportability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronalg/archive/2014/03/24/sql-server-2014-and-sharepoint-supportability.aspx)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx#section3

Comment: It is not supported but what if we run SQL server 2014 in compatibility mode, it can work that way (of course still not supported by MS) so my question is if someone has ever used this combination?

Comment: I dont think it is good idea as this your production. I am ok with Dev farm...It may work but once it broke then you will be out of luck as your DBs upgraded to sql 2014 and cant go back and MSFT will not rescue you.

Comment: yeah you may be right we should not go for anything in production environment which is not recommended by Microsoft.